# Javascript refresh main page after closing child window (popup)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 3 php files: `view.php`, `edit.php` and `edit2.php`.

I use `view.php` to display content of my DB tables, `edit.php` to edit a specific row (I use textboxes etc.) and `edit2.php` to write any changes to my database. After the query is successfully executed, `edit2.php` uses `header("Location: edit.php");` to display the chosen row again (I use session variables in `edit.php` and unset them on `view.php`).

`edit.php` and `edit2.php` are opened in a small popup window. Now what I would like to have is when I close my small window, `view.php` should be refreshed.

I tried using `onunload` but what it does it is triggers itself each time a button is clicked in `edit.php` to send data to `edit2.php`, so when it returns to `edit.php`, it's blank because session variables are unset due to refreshing of `view.php`.

I have this strange feeling, that I might have explained it in a twisted way... Nevertheless, I would need some help.

Comment: use ajax to call edit2.php, so ononload event won't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is open a new window using `window.open('edit.php')`

Here is the [documentation for window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Then watch for when the new window is closed, and refresh the page when that happens. Unfortunately there is no 'on close' event that's fired, but there is a property `window.closed` that you can watch to see when the window is closed.

So this is what you should do:

```
var win = window.open('edit.php','Edit Row','width=800,height=600,status=0,toolbar=0');   
var timer = setInterval(function() {   
    if(win.closed) {  
        clearInterval(timer);  
        location.reload() 
    }  
}, 1000);
```

Comment: How can I do this, when I have my `window.open()` function in form:
`<form blabla onSubmit="window.open(...)">`